# Could I use a Terminal command to get last shutdown when I don't have the password?

Tags: terminal

I am looking for a Terminal Command to get the following information about a disk

- Last shutdown
- Last reboot

I need to be able to specify the disk because I will be booting from a different, external, disk, or possibly from macOS Recovery.

**Note:** I do not have the user password to log in.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't have the password for the disk"?

Comment: That's it, I mean I don't have the user password for the startup volume.  Thank you.

Comment: Not specific for drive but try `last reboot` and `last shutdown`